# How to run Py_Initialize in embedded python with virtualenv using C API?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, virtualenv

In my C++ application I am using embedded python interpreter using the stable C API to execute python scripts. It works well, but I want to extend this functionality to be able to configure a virtualenv path to use that instead of the system's python packages.

What I gathered is that I have to set some variables before calling Py_Initialize to make it use the virtualenv. I tried a lot of combinations of calling Py_SetPythonHome, Py_SetPath, Py_SetProgramName with specific paths and setting environment variables PATH, VIRTUAL_ENV, PYTHONPATH, but none of the combinations seem so to work.

In my last attempt I appended my PATH environment variable with the virtualenv's bin directory, added the VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable with the virtualenv path, set the PYTHONPATH environent variable to the list of subdirectories of the virtualenv and called Py_SetPythonHome with the virtualenv path:

```
std::string old_path = utils::Environment::getEnvironmentVariable("PATH").value();
utils::Environment::setEnvironmentVariable("PATH", ((virtualenv_path_ / "bin").string() + ":" + old_path).c_str());
utils::Environment::setEnvironmentVariable("VIRTUAL_ENV", virtualenv_path_.string().c_str());
auto lib_path = virtualenv_path_ / "lib" ;
std::string python_dir_name;
for (auto const& dir_entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{lib_path}) {
  if (minifi::utils::string::startsWith(dir_entry.path().filename().string(), "python")) {
    python_dir_name = dir_entry.path().filename().string();
    break;
  }
}
static const auto package_path = lib_path / python_dir_name / "site-packages";
static const auto python_dir_path = lib_path / python_dir_name;
static size_t virtualenv_path_size = virtualenv_path_.string().size();
Py_SetPythonHome(Py_DecodeLocale(virtualenv_path_.c_str(), &virtualenv_path_size));
utils::Environment::setEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", (package_path.string() + "/:" + lib_path.string() + "/").c_str());
```

After starting up the application it seems that I have the right directories set, but I still get an error (the virtualenv path is /home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv):

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv'
  PYTHONPATH = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/:/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/lib/'
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/',
    '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/lib/',
    '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/user/pythonrunnerapp/pyenv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f33a4b50780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

If I don't do any of this, but I activate the environment before running the application and the executing it from that shell it manages to use the virtual environment, but I would like to be able to activate it from the application when needed.
What is the proper way to use an embedded python in a virtualenv here without the need to activate it beforehand?